# Adding a css class on scroll via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation with an empty div in each anchor tag that I am styling on hover.

html

```
<li><a href="#events">SPECIAL EVENTS <div></div></a></li>
```

css

```
a:hover div, a:active div{
    color: $black;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: $black;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I also have a active class that I am attaching on click with some js. This is currently working correctly.

```
var currentDiv;

function addSelected(){

if(currentDiv !== undefined){
    $(currentDiv).removeClass("active");    
}

currentDiv = $(this).find('div');
$(currentDiv).addClass("active");
}

$(".menu a").click(addSelected);
```

What I am trying to do is attached that same active class based on the user scroll. I get most of it working, but I can't seem to figure how how to attached the class to the div, and not the anchor itself. Here is the js I'm working with.

js

```
    // Cache selectors
var lastId,
topMenu = $("#desktop-nav"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
// All list items
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) { return item; }
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
// Get container scroll position
var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

// Get id of current scroll item
var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
 if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop){
   return this;
 }  
});
// Get the id of the current element
cur = cur[cur.length-1];
var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    // Set/remove active class
    menuItems

    //.parent().removeClass("active")
    //.end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");

    .removeClass("active");
    end().filter($("[href='#"+id+"']")).find('div').addClass("active");

    console.log(id);
}                   
});
```

I think the part that I am trying to change is this

```
"[href='#"+id+"']").parent()
```

but everything I try is either not working or giving me errors.

**EDIT**

Here is the fiddle that I am trying to modify.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/)

Comment: What is your current status. Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: it's attaching the class to the parent of the anchor tag instead of the div tag that is inside of the anchor

Comment: Please provide the complete code where you are stuck.

Comment: @dan, I updated the js to include all the code that I am using, Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `children()` instead of `parent()` or `find()`

**Example:**

```
 if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // add/remove active class on div
       menuItems
         .children().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").children().addClass("active");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to use find() like in your click handler:

```
"[href='#"+id+"']").find('div')
```

Comment: This seems to find the first one, but still adds the class to the parent, even if I update the code to this  `.end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").find('div').addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've tried...

```
"[href='#"+id+"']").parent().find('div')
```

and/or...

```
"[href='#"+id+"'].div"
```

...if so, are you able to add a `class` or `id` to the `div` and target it that way?

Comment: Yes I can add a class to the div, but I'm still not sure how to target the class with the above code.